# May I include in ActiveRecord model a new relation from my plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, redmine-plugins

I'm creating a plugin for Redmine. I want to use the core Issue model, but I want to include in it a relation with my model, which created in the plugin structure. How can I patch the `Issue` model for including a new relationship in my plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a decorator in your main project to decorate the `Issue` model:

```
# app/decorators/issue_decorator.rb
Redmine::Issue.class_eval do
  has_many :blurps # or whatever your model is called
end
```

Answer (score 0):

example with `Project` model

```
require 'project'

module ProjectPatch
  def self.included(base)
    base.has_one :project_settings
  end
end

Project.send :include, ProjectPatch
```